# Can't create template which includes site content

Tags: site-template

I'm trying to create a site template which includes the content from the site but I keep getting an error and the template creation fails. The error is as follows:

> Sorry, something went wrong
>
> Microsoft.Workflow.Client.ActivityNotFoundException: The activity named 'WorkflowXaml_a6e17c88_46d6_4f20_bbf5_5a431fbe8636' from scope '/spo/56654289-5fe6-4a6e-9927-a95e37949fe4/34a8e849-276d-4463-87bb-8727d8627eb0/33095035-a88b-43d3-add8-ce14aa2398cc' was not found. HTTP headers received from the server - ActivityId: --------. NodeId: . Scope: . Client ActivityId : --------. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error

Any thoughts as to how I can avoid this error and create the site template with all the content included (content: 5 task lists, calendars, doc library with about 20 empty folders, and a few other apps)?

Answer (score 0):

Delete the workflow on the lists before attempting to save as template.

Be careful though -- you will need to re-create the workflow (as a reusable workflow) so be sure you have it documented.